# How to remove the author and date of creation details from an article?

Tags: php, joomla

Am creating a sample website using Joomla. I am just a beginner. How to hide the author details and date of creation from an article published?

Answer (score 1):

While creating the article on the right side panel you will see **Parameters(Advanced)** there all the parameters will be set to Use Global by default change the your requirements to **Hide**.

This also can be handled from the editing of the article.

Comment: @alice if you got answer it is better to choose that answer as useful so that others who are searching for the same question may know that it is useful and wont post duplicate questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, the author will be shown by default in a [meta-tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_tag) - invisible to normal users, but visible to search engines and everybody with a bit of HTML knowledge.

To hide the author's name completely, go to **Global Configuration > Show Author Meta Tag : No**

(A not-yet-mentioned third place where you could hide the author name: **Article Manager > Parameters**. Actually, that's where I'd do it if I wanted to set it for all the articles: I could still activate it per article or menu item, but *by default*, it will fall through to Hide.)

Comment: Cheers man :). Really nice info for me this is first time to listen. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is simple go to Menu and select your desire menu when it loads. See Article Options and Hide all or choose No and do the same for articles as well.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to srinivas answer, depending on how you set your site up, you might find the parameters under the Menu Item you have setup for the section/category/article. For instance, if you have a menu item pointing to a category/blog, you'll see the params in there.